# SMS Gateway to send and receive sms in Nigeria

Tags: sms-gateway

Please help me and suggest me some sms gateways that provide two way sms in Nigeria.
I have created a web application. I need to send and receive sms through this application and maintain a log about the same in my db.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Twilio** as SMS Gateway.

URL: https://www.twilio.com/sms, https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/ng

Comment: I have tried twilio, but it does not provide the local number in Nigeria and also it doesn't provide the reply message on the sms sent.

Comment: In twilio I see the pricing for Nigeria.                                                 **Airtel** $0.01517 per message
**Glo Mobile** $0.01517 per message
**MTN** $0.01517 per message
**Etisalat** $0.01625 per message
**Starcomms** $0.10833 per message .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 I think twilio has this service for Nigeria also. You can contact with Twilio support team.

Comment: Yes, I have contacted them and they told me they don't offer local number there and they don't provide two way sms service there.